# So many pythons, which do I need?

Tags: python, macos

It seems I have several Python versions installed on my Mac (High Sierra). Do I really need more than one each of Python 2.7 and the most recent Python3?

I am primarily concerned about confusion when adding modules to the environments.

Here are the python executables I can find, excluding symlinks. Do I need them all? Does Apple need one version just for the OS? (Maybe that's Ruby I'm thinking of._)

```
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/share/python
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/libexec/bin/python
```

Comment: Depends if you want to use python 3 or 3.  Just be aware python 2 is deprecated in 2020.  So I would use python 3.7.1

Comment: Did you check whether some of them aren't just *symlink*s to others?

Comment: It seems with some research python does actually come pre-installed on the mac.  I would *guess* the three of the same version were pre-installed and the 3.7.1 was installed from the internet.

Comment: @CristiFati -- yes, as I said in my question.

Comment: So one person says I definitely need /usr/bin/python because some system functionality depends on it and another says I definitely don't expressing certainty using boldface. I guess I will leave it as three pythons. One each of the latest versions of 2 and 3 and /usr/bin/python, for which I will never install packagess or upgrades.

@tripleee: I used to use macports and homebrew but found I had several packages multiply installed. As I am currently troubleshooting a failure installing a pacakge simplified to one installer. Any comments you have on alternatives would be welcome.

Comment: No experience with MacPorts. Mixing multiple third-party software managers certainly rounds like a road to complications. Don't forget you need `pip` in the mix as well, though `virtualenv` lets you encapsulate that nicely (each separate env gets its own private stack of `pip`-managed packages).

Comment: I think the boldface comment in Keith's answer is trying to say that breakage will be moderate, and you can probably easily live without those non-oritical applications (and even perhaps never notice any difference ... or if you come from Windows you just shrug and think it's normal that things don't always work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MacOS, you *need* to have the system-installed Python 2 in `/usr/bin/python` because some system functionality depends on it.

If you have other versions installed via Homebrew or etc, that's strictly optional.  For developing code in Python, definitely install a recent version of Python 3; you should not be developing new code in the legacy version 2. It will run out of support in a year or so, and many important third-party libraries etc have already abandoned support for it.

If you do need to maintain Python 2 code, having a Homebrew version of the most recent Python 2.7.13 is probably a good idea.  The system `/usr/bin/python` is at version 2.7.10 as of MacOS Mojave; and if we extrapolate from Apple's update policy history for third-party open-source software in the system, it will probably remain there for many years.

Homebrew is just one of many ways to install additional Python versions, but since this is what you seem to be using already (as indicated by the `/usr/local/Cellar` paths) I will not go into alternatives.

For switching between versions, `virtualenv` is the common baseline, though there are many add-ons like `pyenv` etc which add convenience features or alternative models for switching between projects which require different versions of Python and various packages.

Comment: `grep python /usr/bin/*` brings up a number of hits, though obviously some of them are bogus, and many are related to Python itself; but e.g. the `xattr` command is a system utility which depends on Python 2.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** this answer might be primarily based opinioned.

First, in macos, I encourage you to use [`brew`](https://brew.sh/) to install python. So, if you want to instal Python 3 run:

```
$ brew install python
```

Probably it is already installed, so to update it run:

```
$ brew upgrade python
```

This will upgrade to the latest version of Python 3. In general, if you start a new project you should use Python 3. **Remember that Python 2 will be deprecated at the end of this year 2019.**

Second, I highly recommend you to use [virtual environments](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) to avoid having issues with dependencies. You can create a virtual environment running:

```
$ python3 -m venv .ven
```

This will create a virtual environment in `.venv` in your current working directory.

As an alternative you can use [`pipenv`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to track dependencies too which I also encourage you to install using brew.

```
$ brew install pipenv
```

Then you create a virtual environment running:

```
$ pipenv --three
```

Keep in mind that you will have two versions of Python in your machine `python` which is Python 2 (installed by default in your machine) and `python3` which is Python 3. Then, if you want to run Python 2 just type `python`, while if you want to run Python 3 type `python3`.

Finally, you can also keep track of several python versions using [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). This is very useful if you need to use multiple versions of Python for example Python 3.1, 3.2, 3.3..., 3.6, 3.7.1, 3.7.2, 3.7.3, etc.

This is what has been useful in my experience using macOS. You could also use [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)) to completely isolate your environment, but probably the first two points is enough if you are a beginner.

Comment: Thanks, good advice re virtualenv. However I am currently troubleshooting a problem installing certain packages, so at least temporarily I am working to eliminate complexity. I will return to using it when I get the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

While Python 3.x is what python solutions should be implemented in today, many existing python applications, modules, etc, are implemented and maintained in 2.7 or lower. Sometimes you'll find multiple versions of python on your computer because applications you've downloaded in the past had you install them so their application would work properly on your machine. As long as you don't want, or need applications that may depend on past versions of python, you can update to the latest one and delete the old versions.

If you are planning on developing in python, and you can use the latest version, you should definitely do so. If you rid of the versions of python on your machine, applications, modules/scripts, etc may not work or function properly.

Python comes pre-installed on Mac OS X, but it is not required to be on your machine for your computer to function, **just the applications that may be on your machine that may use Python**.